# callback via taptool presents datatable

Tags: datatable, modal-dialog, bokeh

From what I can tell in my limited review of bokeh documentation the ability to click on a glyph on a plot then present a Dialog box or Datatable is a feature not yet available.  I do not want the Datatable to be presented until a glyph has been selected.  Would ideally like the ability to hide the Dialog or Datatable as well.

It seems that bokeh.models.widgets.dialog were deprecated sometime after 0.10.0.  I could use that but its not available in python 3.7 at this point.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Some features are not officially supported but sometimes one can come up with a work-arounds like this one (tested on Bokeh v1.0.4):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, DataTable, TableColumn, CustomJS

plot = figure(tools = 'tap')
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x = list(range(6)), y = [x ** 2 for x in range(6)]))
circles = plot.circle('x', 'y', source = source, size = 20)
slider = Slider(start = -1, end = 5, value = 6, step = 1, title = "i", width = 300)
columns = [TableColumn(field = "x", title = "x"), TableColumn(field = "y", title = "x**2")]
table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, width = 320)
plot.js_on_event('tap', CustomJS(args = {'table': table, 'source': source, 'slider': slider}, code = '''
        const selected_index = source.selected.indices[0] 
        if (selected_index != null) 
            table.height = 0;
        else
            table.height = slider.value * 25 + 25;'''))
callback_code = """ i = slider.value;
                    new_data = {"x": [0,1,2,3,4,5], "y": [0,1,4,9,16,25]}
                    table.source.data = new_data
                    table.height = i * 25 + 25;  """
callback = CustomJS(args = dict(slider = slider, table = table), code = callback_code)
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
show(column(slider, plot, table))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Tony.  However when I load this code and execute it I get nothing on the web page.  What version of bokeh is required to run this.  I'm still on 0.13.0 (hope to be at 1.0.4 in the next day or so).

Comment: Please upgrade to latest Bokeh version 1.0.4